# Assign IP address in docker with a bridge network which has no IP

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose

I want to ask a static IP within the docker container.
I can assign an IP address if there is the `IPAM` configuration in the network.

```yaml
version: "2.1"
services:
  nginx:
    image: ghcr.io/linuxserver/nginx
    container_name: nginx
    volumes:
      - ./config:/config
    ports:
      - 443:443
    restart: always
    networks:
      br-uplink:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.1.2

networks:
  br-uplink:
    driver: bridge
    name: br-uplink
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: "192.168.1.0/24"
          gateway: "192.168.1.1"
```

but if there is no `IPAM`, then this does not work.

```
$ docker compose up -d
[+] Running 1/2
 ⠿ Network br-uplink  Created
 ⠋ Container nginx    Creating
Error response from daemon: user specified IP address is supported only when connecting to networks with user configured subnets
```

So if I remove `ipv4_address` and `IPAM` configuration, then a random address is assigned.
and if I assign manually within the container, it works.

```
docker compose exec nginx bash
ip add flush dev eth0
ip add add 192.168.11.2/24 dev eth0
```

How can I make this possible automatically?
I don't want to create my own `Dockerfile` for this, it would be happy if this can be done within the `docker-compose.yml`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you need to know the container-private IP address at all?  You can use the Compose service name `nginx` as a host name to communicate between containers without knowing the IP address, and in most platforms and environments the IP address is unreachable from outside Docker.  Do things work okay if you delete _all_ of the `networks:` blocks, and don't try to manually configure anything?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, and yes I partially agree with you. but what I actually want to do is to use the container for real networking, for example, combined with `veth` and/or `openvswitch`. this is easier if I use `lxc`, but I want this more lightweight like docker.